# How to create rails route with constrants for numbers-only that accepts empty parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, constraints

I have created some route like this:

```
get 'foo/:offset' => 'foo#action', :as => :foo, :constraint => { id: /\d+/ }
```

It works fine, but: I want rails to route `/foo` to `foo#action` if no parameter specified, so not only urls like `/foo/123` will be routed but simple `/foo` too.

How can I change constraint for this? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it's a simple one:

Create a route for `/foo`, and another for `/foo/:offset` to the same controller and action!